# Automapper inside service when unit testing

Tags: c#, mstest

I am wondering how to configure automapper inside some unit tests.
The service does a few things:

- Fetches a user
- Created an integration object
- Maps integration object
- Updates the user

Service:

```
public void Update(UserUpdateDto userUpdateDto)
    {
        var user = _userValidationService.ValidateUser(userUpdateDto.Id);

        var integration = _integrationService.UpdateIntegration(userUpdateDto.Integration, userUpdateDto.Id);

        var integrationGateway = _mapper.Map<IntegrationGateway>(integration);
        user.Integration = integrationGateway;

        _repository.Update(user);
        _repository.Commit();
    }
```

Test

```
//Arrange
        

        InMemoryRepository.Add(userGateway); 

        _mockIntegrationService.Setup(x => x.UpdateIntegration(It.IsAny<IntegrationDto>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(integration);

        //Act
        _usersService.Update(userUpdateDto);

        //Assert
        var integrationResult = InMemoryRepository.GetAll<UserGateway>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == 1)!.Integration;
        Assert.AreEqual(userUpdateDto.Integration.WooConsumerKey, integrationResult.WooConsumerKey);
```

I have thought about setting up an expected return for the map method but this would defeat the purpose of the test?

If my service is not very testable then I would appreciate advise on how I could refactor this. Cheers

.NET 6, MSTEST

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

Just done some more research and I have come to the realisation that Automapper should NOT be mapped.

I have added this in the `TestInitialise` of the test class

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(new IntegrationProfile()));
        _mapper = new Mapper(configuration);
```

Comment: I think you are on right direction. are you getting the same issue? Also instead of posting answer just update your question with as much detail you can.